# Move all of my domain computers to another domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, domaincontroller

I know there is a tool called netdom.exe which could join a computer to a domain automatically,but I need a script or program that could run on my server and move all (not one) my domain members (PCs) to another domain automatically and simultaneously! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free Active Directory Migration Tool (ADMT) from Microsoft should be able to help you here...